# Create nested json file

Tags: python, json, file, nested

I want to create a json file that can be used as a configuration file. I have different files from multiple companies that report the same information with different column names.

I want to use the information provided in the json file to run a python script to consolidate all the information from all files and companies in one master file.

The structure looks like follows:

```
{"companies":
    {"company1": [
        {"path": "C:/USER/Path/Company1/",
         "files": [
            {
                {"_CO": {"ID": "ID", "Report Number": "Report_Number"}},
                {"_TR": {"ID": "Trade_Ident", "Report Number": "Number of Report"}},    
            },
         ],
        },
    ],
    },

    {"company2": [
        {"path": "C:/USER/Path/Company2/",
         "files": [
            {
                {"_CO": {"ID": "Identification", "Report Number": "Report-Number"}},
                {"_TR": {"ID": "Ident", "Report Number": "NumberReport"}},  
            },
         ],
        },
    ],
    },
},
```

However, I receive the following error when trying to read the .json in python.

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in
>   double quotes: line 6 column 5 (char 90)

To read the file I use:

```
import json

path = "/user_folder/USER/Desktop/Data/"

file = "ConfigFile.json"

with open(path+file) as f:
    my_test = json.load(f)
```

Any help appreciated, as I can't figure out my mistake in the file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting error because your `json` file is incorrectly formatted and thus calling `json.load()` will raise an `JSONDecodeError`.

Your `json` structure should look like,

```
{
    "companies": {
        "company1": [
            {
                "path": "C:/USER/Path/Company1/",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "_CO": {
                            "ID": "ID",
                            "Report Number": "Report_Number"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_TR": {
                            "ID": "Trade_Ident",
                            "Report Number": "Number of Report"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "company2": [
            {
                "path": "C:/USER/Path/Company2/",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "_CO": {
                            "ID": "Identification",
                            "Report Number": "Report-Number"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_TR": {
                            "ID": "Ident",
                            "Report Number": "NumberReport"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You have some object (the ones with curly braces) without keys, for example in

```
{
    {"_CO": {"ID": "ID", "Report Number": "Report_Number"}}, ...
```

Objects in JSON are key-value pairs. Just remove the external set of braces and it should be ok.

You can use some online JSON formatter/validator just like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), and it will easily point out the problem. Otherwise, you can use some JSON linter for your editor. It just does the work for you and also improves indentation :)